# Fix flv file with small errors

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a couple of flv files downloaded with `youtube-dl`. When they are played they fail after a few minutes with:

```
Unsupported video codec (X)
```

where X is e, 9, or b.

My guess is that one block is corrupt. As I cannot download them again (the files have since been removed) can I somehow fix or skip the corruption?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you try different playback tools on different platforms?

Comment: mplayer and vlc tried on LinuxMint. They die exactly the same place. I do not have access to other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to find an FLV format decoder, and have it scan the files to make sure that at least the container format is complete and correct. [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) parses and converts FLV format files, but you may not be able to use it with a file containing unknown video formats.

With a bit of programming, the [FLV container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) is pretty simple to decode. Once you've scanned the file and listed its contained formats, you can then choose which blocks to ignore and skip.

Comment: It seems the flv-container is broken at exactly the place VLC gives up. Can I somehow ask FFmpeg to skip some flv-packets and re-sync the flv-stream?

Comment: If the container itself is broken, then you may be out of luck, as the format is chained; each block indicates its length, and thus where the next block's header is located. If you don't know where the headers are, you're going to have a tough time decoding them.